# Check whether sublist is in list

Tags: java, list, sublist

I have two lists, L1 and L2. I need to check whether L2 is a contiguous sublist of L1. L1 may be smaller or larger than L2 (but never exactly the same size). They are both lists of strings, however I need to check whether the element in L1 contains the element in L2 (rather than direct equality)

Whats a nice, succinct way of doing this? At the moment I just have two iterators chasing each other but this seems inelegant

Comment: If all elements of L2 should be in L1, you could call `L1.containsAll(L2)`

Comment: How about showing us your "two iterators chasing each other"?

Comment: The iterators seems the best solution. Just look for the first coincidence and try to compare the whole list from there.
Could you show us your code? maybe we can improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Set `i` to 0.

Iterate through `L1`, checking for an element matching `L2[i]`. When you find it, increment `i`. When you don't find it, set it back to 0.

If `i` reaches the length of `L2`, you've found the contents of `L2`, in order, within `L1`.

```
public boolean containsInOrder(List<Foo> list, List<Foo> pattern) {
     int i=0;
     for(Foo item : list) {
        if(Objects.equals(item,pattern.get(i))) {
           i++;
        } else {
           i=0;
        }
        if(i == pattern.size()) {
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Small bug -- will throw an exception if L2 is an empty list. I will leave the fix as "an exercise for the reader".

Comment: ... and will return false if both lists are empty. Also leaving the fix as "an exercise for the reader".

Answer (score 0):

Recursive answer because I'm feeling cheeky:

```
 public boolean containsInOrder(List<Foo> list, List<Foo> pattern) {
     if(pattern.isEmpty()) {
         return true;
     }

     if(list.isEmpty()) {
         return false;
     }

     if(Objects.equals(head(list), head(pattern)) {
         return containsInOrder(tail(list), tail(pattern));
     }

     // else 
     return containsInOrder(tail(list), pattern);
 }

 private Foo head(List<Foo> l) {
     return l.get(0);
 }

 private List<Foo> tail(List<Foo> l) {
     return l.subList(1,l.size());
 }
```

Don't use it in production code: since Java hasn't got tail call optimisation this will chew up too much stack if the list is long. But it's a fun example of a recursive solution.